# Facebook like button doesn't show in Chrome

Tags: facebook, google-chrome, button

I added a Facebook like button to my site, which was generated by the Facebook tool

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

it works perfectly in FF and IE

[image]

But doesn't want to work in Chrome 9

[image]

Does anybody know why it happens this way ?

Comment: Works for me in 9.0.597.94 Do you have a strange screen resolution or maybe some browser display settings that are causing things to get lost? What version of Chrome did you test on?

Comment: My screen resolution is 1440x900 but I haven't heard it could affect such thing as a button. My Chrome is the same as yours 9.0.597.47. I'm glad it works for you because I tested everything including safari on my phone. It works everywhere except my chrome

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Sorry guys, it was really stupid of me.
The cause of this mess is a Facebook Disconnect extension I enabled a few weeks ago - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ejpepffjfmamnambagiibghpglaidiec

Since it works for you I started exploring my own Chrome.
Thanks for your support, you helped me to understand the issue.

Comment: I just had the same issue :)

Comment: I'm glad my experience helped someone else to save a few hours of thinking, googling and debugging. As for the future I decided to install two separate browsers. One with all the adblocking plugins for comfortable browsing. Second - for work and testing, without any plugins and adblocks.

Comment: You actually saved my butt on this, had the same issue and was totally puzzled. +1

Comment: I discovered the Chrome DoNotTrackMe extension has the same effect. Once I disabled it, the button showed.

Answer (score 1):

FYI - for anyone that finds this, Avast is blocking social media sites by default now with their web plug in!  Grrr...